# Symbol used in printf

Tags: c, unicode, printf

I was wondering what the symbol used in `printf` means. I tried googling but couldn't find the right name for it[image: Program to print character and string lengths]

And here's the statement in question represented using the Unicode **BOTTOM SQUARE BRACKET** character, **U+23B5**:

```
printf("⎵%d\n", br);
```

(This is intended to show what the handwritten code looks like; that character won't appear in the actual code.)

Comment: That usually means the space character

Comment: This is a common notation for "space" in hand-written code

Comment: It's a visible symbol for a space. It allows us to clearly and precisely show multiple spaces, too, which would be undistinguishable otherwise.

Comment: Also to be seen on the mobile (aka cell phone) texting keypad.

Comment: I've complained before about screenshots of code, but this is the first time I've see a photo of handwritten code. It's actually not a bad question, though; that symbol for space is used almost exclusively in handwritten code. In an actual source file, it would just be a space (which would be clear enough when viewed with a monospaced font). See also [this answer](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/91256/7888)

Comment: You might also see this `substitute blank` symbol used for a space character too: `␢`

Comment: Looks like a [BOTTOM SQUARE BRACKET](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/23b5/index.htm)  Yet I like the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42375914/2410359) better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a visible symbol for a space. It allows us to clearly and precisely show multiple spaces, too, which would be undistinguishable otherwise.

It can be represented also in print with '␣', a symbol named 'Open box', which has a codepoint U+2423 (decimal: 9251) in Unicode. Source: Wikipedia [Whitespace character – Unicode – Substitutes](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Whitespace_character&oldid=755493243#Visible_space), the last table in the section. (Wikipedia page version dated 18 December 2016.)

Comment: Cheers. Strange I didn't see it anywhere else before.

Answer (score 6):

Usually, that's a placeholder used to count the number of individual spaces.

Answer (score 0):

It is a symbol used to display space character clearly. It is clear and helps to count number of spaces with ease.

As Keith Suggested You Can Refer To This [How can I best display a blank space character?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/91255/how-can-i-best-display-a-blank-space-character/91256#91256).

[image]